# How to use a passed through integer in a range when copying cells

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I've looked around on the internet and found no sucess.  my problem is that im trying to copy the range of P6 to P(value of an integer passed in to the sub) from the first worksheet to values B2 to B(the value passed through) of the second worksheet:

---

```
sub copy_cells(length as integer)

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2: B+length").Value = ActiveSheet("Sheet1").Range   ("P6:P+length").Value

end sub
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2), Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(length, 2)).Value
 = 
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 16), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(length, 16)).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reference the range the way you are doing it, it won't work. Start with "B2" as your target range and then resize it to the appropriate length.

```
Sub copy_cells(length As Integer)
Dim outRange As Range
Dim inRange As Range

    Set outRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")
    Set inRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P6")

    Set outRange = outRange.Resize(length)
    Set inRange = inRange.Resize(length)

    outRange.Value = inRange.Value

    Set outRange = Nothing
    Set inRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub copy_cells(length as integer)

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2: B" & length).Value = ActiveSheet("Sheet1").Range   ("P6:P" & length).Value

end sub
```

this should work - if not, you may need to create the range variable in a separate statement and then use it in the statement above.